# Striped highlighted region using matplitlib/python

Tags: python, graphics, matplotlib

I have a line graph done, and I want to highlight a region as in the graph below

[image]

The point is, instead of a solid colour (as grey in the sides)I want a striped thing as in the center.... Does any one have any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make a vertical span across the axis using [axvspan](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.axvspan).  To get the hatches you can use the hatch parameter.

```
axvspan(xmin, xmax, hatch='/')
```

You may have to play with the `zorder` parameter as well to get the span underneath your line graph.